# How to prove geometrically the limit $\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{1-\cos{x}}{x}$ using squeeze theorem

Tags: geometry, limits, trigonometry

Here, I ask how to geometrically prove the limit 
\begin{equation}\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{1-\cos{x}}{x}\end{equation} 
using squeeze theorem. I see so many proofs for the other important limit \begin{equation}\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin{x}}{x}\end{equation}
But it seems that no one discussed the first one yet.

Comment: Just curious, but do you HAVE to use squeeze theorem? THere are so many other ways to do this limit

Comment: Yes, I HAVE to use squeeze theorem.